# Alert class ID via document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load "test.php?id=1" on an alert box using id="bnt_support"

Example:

```
  <a href="test.php?id=1" onclick="top.location='test.php?id=1';" id="bnt_support" class="MenuItem sprt_05">test</a>
```

I did try calling `bnt_support` directly with `document.getElementById` but it did not work.

```
<script>
alert(document.getElementById('bnt_support').value)
</script>
```

Do I need to call the class `MenuItem sprt_05` also?

Comment: Hello there, I'm trying but is not working. https://jsfiddle.net/76ndu2mr/

Comment: Why did you put a `.value` at the end? `document.getElementById('bnt_support').getAttribute("href")` is a string. It’s _the string that you want_. `.value` would be a _non-existing property of that string_, so of course it will be `undefined`. Remove that `.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a>` elements don’t have a `value`. You’re trying to get the `href`, not the `value`. Because the `href` *property* is usually a full URL, you actually need the `href` *attribute*, so use this:

```
document.getElementById('bnt_support').getAttribute("href")
```

As mentioned before, the `href` property would be:

```
document.getElementById('bnt_support').href
```